# copying sections including pages in Onenote API

Tags: onenote-api

I've looked through here https://dev.onenote.com/.

There doesn't seem to be an example of how to duplicate a section of Onenote. All I'm trying to do is take one section of onenote and replicate it 10 times. Right now, I'm just manually `right clicking` --> `Move or Copy...`

Can anybody show me how to do this using the Onenote API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-copy

You can use the Copy Sections API.